# Could not find a method to load image, NullPointerException

Tags: image, processing

I have a very small code just to try out some stuff for a game I am going to make and I cant seem to fix this problem, I have the files in my data file and I think that everything is written correctly. Thanks in advance.

```
PImage background, moon;
void setup() {
  background = loadImage("Background.jpg");
  moon = loadImage("moon.jgp");
  fullScreen();
  background(background);
}
void draw() {
  image(moon, width/2, height/2);
}
```

Comment: How do you know that your image is in the correct location and you have the spelling correct? Also which language is this? If Java, then use `if (Files.exists("moon.jgp")) System.out.println("Image exists");`. I am pretty sure the filename is incorrect, it should be  `moon.jpg` rather than `moon.jgp` (note the p and g are backwards)

Comment: Omg thank you so much, the problem was the jpg, this language is processing a java based language for games